# scribe is an overloaded tag

Tags: discussion, tags, overlap

It appears that [scribe](/questions/tagged/scribe) has become an overloaded tag.

Scribe is used for a [simple OAuth Java library](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) and more recently [the open source server for aggregating streaming log data written by Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/scribe/wiki).

The author of the Java OAuth library has recently moved his project to scribe-java to avoid confusion.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OAuth library is now known as scribe-java, then questions about that library should be using [scribe-java](/questions/tagged/scribe-java) as a tag instead of scribe.  There are only 18 tags, so it should be an easy matter for the community to go through and update these questions as appropriate.  Once the tag is created, it will appear in the auto-complete whenever someone starts typing in `scribe` for a tag, so hopefully it shouldn't be a big issue going forward.

The tag wiki should make the purpose and difference between these tags clear.

Comment: I am not sure I have the reputation points to change tags. How does one get this to happen?